# Get request TypeError: this is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have two functions :

This one checks if a username is already used in database:

```
public async checkIfExistUsername(){
      this.authServiceProvider.getDataz("user/"+this.userData.username)
    .then(data => {
      if(data!=null) this.usernameTaken=1;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("Couldn't check email");
    });

  }
```

This one checks if the email is already used in database:

```
public async checkIfExistEmail(){
    this.authServiceProvider.getDataz("userbyemail/" + this.userData.email)
    .then(data => {
      if(data!=null) this.emailTaken=1;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("Couldn't check email");
    });

  }
```

and I have this function that does some popups and shit if email/username exist

```
whatDo(){

      if(this.usernameTaken!=0 && this.emailTaken!=0){
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Erreur',
          subTitle: 'Nom d\'Utilisateur & Email déjà utilisé par un autre Compte.',
          buttons: ['ok']
        });
        alert.present();
      }else if(this.usernameTaken!=0){
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Erreur',
          subTitle: 'Nom d\'Utilisateur déjà utilisé par un autre Compte.',
          buttons: ['ok']
        });
        alert.present();
      }else if(this.emailTaken!=0){
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Erreur',
          subTitle: 'Cet Email déjà utilisé par un autre Compte.',
          buttons: ['ok']
        });
        alert.present();
      }else{

        this.showEtape1 = false;
        this.showEtape2 = true;
        this.showEtape3 = false;
        this.showEtape4 = false;
      }
  }
```

And here’s my getDataz function in AuthService provider:

```
 public getDataz(path): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(apiUrl + path).subscribe((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
    })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  }
```

Im calling these tree functions like this:

```
 this.checkIfExistEmail()
     .then(this.checkIfExistUsername)
     .then(this.whatDo);
```

Here’s the error log:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this is undefined
[59]/SignupPage.prototype.checkIfExistUsername/</<@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1388:17
step@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1249:18
verb/<@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1230:53
[59]/__awaiter</<@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1224:15
t@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:21506
[59]/__awaiter<@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1220:12
[59]/SignupPage.prototype.checkIfExistUsername@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1385:16
F</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14974
onInvoke@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4982:24
F</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14901
F</c</r.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10124
f/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20240
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15649
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4973:24
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15562
F</c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10815
o@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7887
F</h</e.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16823
p@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27646
v@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27893

Stack trace:
c@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752
c@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19461
f/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20233
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15649
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4973:24
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15562
F</c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10815
o@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7887
F</h</e.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16823
p@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27646
v@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27893
```

I tried to call these functions like standalone

```
this.checkIfExistEmail();
```

And it was working well but i wanna run checkIfExistEmail (its async) then checkIfExistUser (its async) then whatDo(its sync)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use bind or arrow function while setting the function as callback.
The `this` value will not be the expected object.

```
this.checkIfExistEmail()
     .then(this.checkIfExistUsername.bind(this))
     .then(this.whatDo.bind(this));
```

With arrow you may have to specify parameters (in case you have them) as well.

```
 this.checkIfExistEmail()
     .then(()=>this.checkIfExistUsername())
     .then(()=>this.whatDo());
```

If you are doing strictly async/await. You do not need to chain like above.

```
await this.checkIfExistEmail();
await this.checkIfExistUsername();
this.whatDo();
```

Comment: Dude it works, been stuck in this for weeks lol, im pretty new to ionic and the whole async and sync functions, could you please explain me how this works ?

Comment: This is not ionic specific.. more related to promises and javascript.

Comment: Here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function and arrow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Yea ikr, i read something about how promises works but the post wasnt showing how to make the app wait for the async function, whats the difference between your solution and my broken one, what does that bind do ? and why i must use a parameter when using bind ?

Comment: bind will set the `this` value of the callback to the calling function's `this` instead of the call location. You will have to specify parameters in _arrow_ not bind. That has nothing to do with async/await. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind